# Change the default REST response to JSON instead XML

Tags: json, xml, netbeans, jersey, glassfish

I'm pretty new with Java REST, I'm currently confused with the response I'm getting from POSTMAN or Chrome is always defaulted to XML and could not change it to JSON unless I remove the XML part. I'm using Jersey 2, Netbeans and Glassfish 4.1.1/4.1

This only returns XML

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

This will return JSON only

```
@GET
@Path("loc/{lat}/{long}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public List<Lastknown> findNearMeLastKnown(@PathParam("lat") String lat, @PathParam("long") String longitude) {
    //List<Lastknown> results =;
    return  super.findNearMeLastKnown(lat,longitude);

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick guess, you have to add the following header in POSTMAN:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Otherwise the server doesn't know which format you want....

Comment: Thanks! That has solved my issue. I thought my code was not working properly because occasionally it returns json but it looks like it was caching the last request which was XML.